TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object in Chartist.js with Vue.js
I'm trying to create a Pie chart using Chartist.js in my Vue.js project and integrate the chartist-plugin-fill-donut plugin. However, I'm encountering a TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object when checking the chart instance.
Error Message:
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
enter image description here
Context:
This error occurs on the line where I check if the chart is an instance of Chartist.Pie.
Steps I've Taken:

Installed chartist, chartist-plugin-fill-donut, and their dependencies.
Imported chartist and the plugin correctly in my component.
Added the necessary CSS files.

Environment:

Vue.js: 3.1.4
Chartist: 1.3.0
chartist-plugin-fill-donut: 0.1.4

What I've Tried:

Verified that the imports are correct.
Checked that the paths to the CSS files are accurate.
Ensured that the chartData is correctly formatted.

Here's my Vue component code:
<template>
  <div ref="chart" class="ct-chart" />
</template>

<script>
import { PieChart } from 'chartist'
import 'chartist/dist/index.css'
import ChartistFillDonut from 'chartist-plugin-fill-donut'

export default {
  name: 'progression-chart',
  data() {
    return {
      chartist: null,
      chartData: {
        labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2'],
        series: [160,60],
      },
      amountValue: true, // Example: assuming you want to format money
    }
  },
  methods: {
    refreshChart() {
      this.chartist.update(this.chartData)
    },
    destroy() {
      if (this.chartist) {
        this.chartist.detach()
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.chartist = new PieChart(this.$refs.chart, this.chartData, {
      donut: true,
      donutWidth: 20,
      startAngle: 10,
      total: 220,
      plugins: [
      ChartistFillDonut({
            items: [{ 
                content: '<h3>160<span class="small">mph</span></h3>'
            }]
        })
      ],
    })
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    this.destroy()
  },
}
</script>

Additional Context:
When I comment out the plugin configuration, the basic donut chart renders without issues, but the fillDonut plugin seems to be causing this problem.
Any ideas on how to resolve this error and use fildonut?
